# Bring bluetooth pairing dialogue to the front

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've a simple service to pair bluetooth devices and it look like this:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if(!extras.containsKey("bluetoothAddress"))
        return;
    String bluetoothAddress = extras.getString("bluetoothAddress");
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if(!adapter.isEnabled()) {
        adapter.enable();
    }
    BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(bluetoothAddress);
    device.createBond();
}
```

It works perfectly fine except that sometimes the pair dialogue pop up and sometimes it show up in my notifications bar and I have to open it manually. Is there any way to make sure that it always pop up to the front?

I've tried to google on it and only thing I can find is that if you stay in bluetooth settings it always pop up, but that seems like a ugly solution. The reason for all of this is that I'm working with automation and want to make sure that when I run my service I get the pair dialogue can just click "Pair".

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I've found this post that explains when the dialog is shown or not: [Bluetooth pairing request on notification bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817571/bluetooth-pairing-request-on-notification-bar)

Resuming, it depends on the result of the shouldShowDialogInForeground() method.

Quoting from the post:

> ... **there are ways of making the dialog show:**
>
> 1. If the device was in discoverable mode recently
> 2. If the device was discovering recently
> 3. If the device was picked in the device picker recently
> 4. If Bluetooth Settings is visible

In my case to force the dialog to appear, I started and canceled a discovery before trying to pair...

**Code/Hack**

```
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery();
//Give it some time before cancelling the discovery
Thread.sleep(1000);
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
//Then do the LeScan and connect to the device
```

**PS**:I know it's a horrible hack but is the only way I got this to work, and the pairing must be done only once for device so it's not so terrible... Also, if anybody finds a better way I'm open to suggestions

Comment: Did you run into issues when you tried it with shorter scan durations?

Comment: In some cases when I shortened the scan duration the hack didn't work (when the sleep time was around half a second the hack failed some times), I think that it was because the Android OS scheduled the scan but didn't manage to scan...

Comment: Something better could be implemented maybe catching the discovery intent or something, but I think it would be overkill for this problem (specially since the pairing dialog needs to be displayed only once)

Comment: I have same issue.

Comment: Which issue exactly? Did you try starting a discovery to force the dialog to the front?

Answer (score 2):

I use following code to resolve the issue

```
if(!BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isDiscovering())
    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery();
//make sure that the device is in discovering
while (!BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isDiscovering());
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
```