# Show bluetooth pairing dialog instead on pairing notification

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

I am stuck at bluetooth pairing issue.
When I call *bluetoothDevice.createBond()* a pairing notification is generate in background. But sometimes shows pairing dialog(In some device), sometimes nothing will be happen. I need to show pairing dialog always.

Note :

- The application is in foreground when generating pairing notification.
- The createBond() method is called inside ConnectionThread Which is start from a connection Service.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem or learn more about it?

Comment: No, the problem still appears.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817571/bluetooth-pairing-request-on-notification-bar/60684696#60684696